# Snowflake SQL - Sum with one-to-many joins

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join, one-to-many

I am trying to write a query that shows when an item on an order was entered or "keyed" in, and then when that item was billed. In certain cases, one item will have multiple billing dates. Because of there being multiple billing dates, I am getting duplicate results of the SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY AND KEYED_GSAR fields.

Below is the query that I am trying to use. It is filtered on one order to illustrate the problem I am having.

```
vwith sales_orders as (
    select 
        O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE,
        O.SALES_ORDER_ID,
        O.MATERIAL_ID,
        O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID,
       sum(distinct o.gsar) as keyed_sales,
       sum(distinct o.sales_order_item_quantity) as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY
    from EDP.RPT_SALES.SALES_ORDERS O
    where O.FISCAL_YR_ID IN (2022,2023)
        AND O.WW_CHANNEL IN ('RENOVATION','INSTALLATION')
        and o.sales_order_id = '0306231843'

        GROUP BY 
        O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE,
        O.SALES_ORDER_ID,
        O.MATERIAL_ID,
        O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID
)

,billing as (
    select 
        B.BILLING_DOC_DATE,
        B.SALES_DOC_ID,
        B.MATERIAL_ID,
        B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID,
        sum(B.BILL_QTY) as BILL_QTY,
        sum(B.GSAR) as GSAR
    from EDP.RPT_SALES.BILLING B
    where b.fiscal_yr_id IN (2022,2023)
        AND b.WW_CHANNEL IN ('RENOVATION','INSTALLATION')

        group by 
        B.BILLING_DOC_DATE,
        B.SALES_DOC_ID,
        B.MATERIAL_ID,
        B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID
)

SELECT

O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE,
LTRIM(O.SALES_ORDER_ID,'0') SALES_ORDER_ID,
LTRIM(O.MATERIAL_ID,'0') MATERIAL_ID,
O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID,
O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY,
KEYED_SALES,
B.BILLING_DOC_DATE,
B.BILL_QTY,
B.GSAR BILLED_SALES


FROM sales_orders O
LEFT JOIN billing B ON O.SALES_ORDER_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ID AND O.MATERIAL_ID = B.MATERIAL_ID AND O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID
```

This order has one material on it, 128470. There was a quantity of 40 ordered for a value of $7,783.60. This material was billed on 4 separate dates, as seen in the BILLING_DOC_DATE column. The SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY and KEYED_SALES values are getting duplicated 4 times. Below are the results I am getting:

| SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE | SALES_ORDER_ID | MATERIAL_ID | SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID | SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY | KEYED_SALES | BILLING_DOC_DATE | BILL_QTY | BILLED_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 40 | 7783.60 | 2023-03-31 | 31 | 6032.29 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 40 | 7783.60 | 2023-03-23 | 5 | 972.95 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 40 | 7783.60 | 2023-04-05 | 3 | 58.77 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 40 | 7783.60 | 2023-03-29 | 1 | 194.59 |

Below are the desired results

| SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE | SALES_ORDER_ID | MATERIAL_ID | SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID | SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY | KEYED_SALES | BILLING_DOC_DATE | BILL_QTY | BILLED_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 40 | 7783.60 | 2023-03-31 | 31 | 6032.29 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 2023-03-23 | 5 | 972.95 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 2023-04-05 | 3 | 58.77 |
| 2023-03-31 | 306231843 | 128470 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 2023-03-29 | 1 | 194.59 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you need a "row number" in the billing data to distinguish which row to output the sales data so that you can avoid repeats. Whilst here, I also suggest you don't use `sum(distinct ...)` unless you have a legitimate reason to omit some data. Given you are summing sales info from a single table it seems very unlikely that  you need `sum(distinct ...)`. i.e. If an order had 2 entries of qty = 20 then the total order qty = 40 isn't it?

```
vwith sales_orders AS (
        SELECT O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE
            , O.SALES_ORDER_ID
            , O.MATERIAL_ID
            , O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID
            , sum(o.gsar) AS keyed_sales
            , sum(o.sales_order_item_quantity) AS SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY
        FROM EDP.RPT_SALES.SALES_ORDERS O
        WHERE O.FISCAL_YR_ID IN (2022, 2023) AND O.WW_CHANNEL IN ('RENOVATION', 'INSTALLATION') AND o.sales_order_id = '0306231843'
        GROUP BY O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE
            , O.SALES_ORDER_ID
            , O.MATERIAL_ID
            , O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID
        )
    , billing AS (
        SELECT B.BILLING_DOC_DATE
            , B.SALES_DOC_ID
            , B.MATERIAL_ID
            , B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID
            , sum(B.BILL_QTY) AS BILL_QTY
            , sum(B.GSAR) AS GSAR
            , row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY B.SALES_DOC_ID
                , B.MATERIAL_ID
                , B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID ORDER BY B.BILLING_DOC_DATE
                ) AS rn
        FROM EDP.RPT_SALES.BILLING B
        WHERE b.fiscal_yr_id IN (2022, 2023) AND b.WW_CHANNEL IN ('RENOVATION', 'INSTALLATION')
        GROUP BY B.BILLING_DOC_DATE
            , B.SALES_DOC_ID
            , B.MATERIAL_ID
            , B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID
        )

SELECT O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE
    , LTRIM(O.SALES_ORDER_ID, '0') SALES_ORDER_ID
    , LTRIM(O.MATERIAL_ID, '0') MATERIAL_ID
    , O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID
    , CASE WHEN b.rn = 1 THEN O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY ELSE 0 END AS SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QTY
    , CASE WHEN b.rn = 1 THEN O.KEYED_SALES ELSE 0 END AS KEYED_SALES
    , B.BILLING_DOC_DATE
    , B.BILL_QTY
    , B.GSAR BILLED_SALES
FROM sales_orders O
LEFT JOIN billing B ON O.SALES_ORDER_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ID AND O.MATERIAL_ID = B.MATERIAL_ID AND O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree on not using sum(distinct). I did not think about that. The row number addition gave me the result that I was looking for.